# Set the WebView content

Tags: objective-c, json, uiwebview

Am consuming a JSON rest service from the web. That JSON has a property called "content", wich is a HTML content, so the JSON file is something like:

```
[{
"id":"4205",
"title":"SomeTitle",
"author":"Homero Simpson",
"content":"<html><head></head><body>Había una vez un molinero cuya única herencia para sus tres hijos eran su molino, su <a href='biblioSonidos://soundID=67'>asno</a> y su <a href='biblioSonidos://soundID=69'>gato</a>. Pronto se hizo la repartición sin necesitar de un clérigo ni de un abogado, pues ya habían consumido todo el pobre patrimonio. Al mayor le tocó el molino, al segundo el asno, y al menor el gato que quedaba. El pobre joven amigo estaba bien inconforme por haber recibido tan poquito. 'Mis hermanos' dijo él, 'pueden hacer una bonita vida juntando sus bienes, pero por mi parte, después de haberme comido al gato, y hacer unas sandalias con su piel, entonces no me quedará más que morir de hambre.'  El gato, que oyó todo eso, pero no lo tomaba así, le dijo en un tono firme y serio: 'No te preocupes tanto, mi buen amo. Si me das un bolso, y me tienes un par de botas para mí, con las que yo pueda atravesar lodos y zarzales, entonces verás que no eres tan pobre conmigo como te lo imaginas.'</body></html>"
}]
```

I need to create a WebView with the code in the "content" property.
So, my question is:
How can set the WebView content from this JSON property?
Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONSerialization to convert the JSON file to a foundation object (which will be an NSDictionary).  Then use loadHTMLString to load the value for the content key:

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToTheJSONFile] options:0 error:&jsonError];
if (json) {
    [webView loadHTMLString:[(NSDictionary *)json objectForKey:@"content"] baseURL:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error loading JSON: %@", jsonError);
}
```

(Pass whatever's appropriate for baseURL instead of nil if you want relative links in the content to work.)